# Table showing "Wrong" Record, but Query returns "Correct" data?

Tags: ms-access

Alright, so here's what happened :

I had a wide table, that needed to be a long table. I used the code below (CODE 1) to fix that problem:

It seemed to have worked, though I am now finding minor errors in the data, while I will need to resolve those, that isn't what this question is about.

In the end, my table looks correctly, and here is an actual record from the database, in fact it is the record that called my attention to the issues:

tbl_CompletedTrainings:

| ID | Employee | Training | CompletedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 306 | Victoria | Clozaril | 5/18/2016 |
| 306 | 20 | 8 | 5/18/2016 |

the second row is to show what the database is actually seeing (FK with both Employee and Training tables) Those tables have the following formats:

tbl_employeeInformation:

| ID | LastName | FirstName | Address | Line2 | City | State | Zip | Site1 | Site2 | Site3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | A. | Victoria | 6 Street |  | City | State | 00000 | 3NNNN |  |  |
| 4 | Eric | A. | 15 Street |  | City | State | 00000 | 3nnnnn |  |  |

tbl_Trainings:

| AutoID | TrainingName | Expiration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Bloodborne | Annual |
| 8 | Clozaril | Annual |

When the query in (CODE 2) is run on this table, the following record is returned

report Query:

| LastName | FirstName | Training | CompletedDate | Site1 | Site2 | Site3 | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Accccc | Eric | Bloodborne Pathogens | 5/18/2016 | 3NN-NN | N/A | N/A | 306 |

Notice that the ID in the report Query is only there as I was checking records, and is called from the tbl_CompletedTrainings. So here's the question, What is happening?! If the record was just wrong, and not pulled I could understand it, but that's not what's happening. Worse still is the date is the correct date for the training the query returns, but not for the training listed in the table.

Related issue, possibly, I had noticed that when I queried the table with a call on the foreign key, it returns records that are 2 off of the requested training number. Notice that this is the case here as well. The training listed, Clozaril, is exactly two further down the line than the training Bloodborne Pathogens, Key 8 and 6 respectively.

Any help would be very much appreciated in this matter, as I can't seem to catch what is causing the issue. Yet it must be something.

**(CODE 1)**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub unXtab()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsxtab As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsutab As DAO.Recordset
Dim counter As Integer
Dim loopint As Integer
Dim qryGetNameID As DAO.Recordset
Dim qryGetTrainingNameID As DAO.Recordset
Dim expires As Date
Dim namevar As String
Dim lname As String
Dim fname As String


Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsxtab = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Employee Training Log];")
If Not (rsxtab.BOF And rsxtab.EOF) Then
    db.Execute "DELETE * FROM tbl_CompletedTrainings;"
    Set rsutab = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_CompletedTrainings WHERE 1 = 2;")
    counter = rsxtab.Fields.Count - 1
    Do
        For loopint = 2 To counter
            namevar = rsxtab.Fields(loopint).Name
            lname = rsxtab("[Last Name]")
            fname = rsxtab("[First Name]")
            
            Select Case namevar
            
                Case "First Name"
                       
                Case "Last Name"
                
                Case "Date of Hire"
                
                Case Else
                
                    If rsxtab.Fields(loopint) <> "" Or Not IsNull(rsxtab.Fields(loopint)) Then
                
                        Set qryGetTrainingNameID = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT AutoID FROM Trainings WHERE [Training Name] = " & Chr(34) & namevar & Chr(34) & ";")
                        Set qryGetNameID = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID FROM tbl_EmployeeInformation WHERE LastName = " & Chr(34) & lname & Chr(34) & _
                                        " AND " & Chr(34) & fname & Chr(34) & ";")
                        
                        rsutab.AddNew
                        
                        Debug.Print lname
                        Debug.Print fname
                        Debug.Print namevar
                        Debug.Print qryGetNameID.Fields(0)
                        Debug.Print qryGetTrainingNameID.Fields(0)
                        
                        rsutab.AddNew
                        rsutab("Employee") = qryGetNameID.Fields(0)
                        rsutab("Training") = qryGetTrainingNameID.Fields(0)
                        rsutab("CompletedDate") = rsxtab.Fields(loopint)
                        rsutab.Update
                    
                    End If
                    
            End Select
            
        Next loopint
        rsxtab.MoveNext
    Loop Until rsxtab.EOF
End If

exitSub:

On Error Resume Next
rsxtab.Close
rsutab.Close
Set rsxtab = Nothing
Set rsutab = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:

MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " on this field: " & namevar, vbOKOnly + vbCritical

End Sub
```

**(CODE 2)**

```
SELECT EI.LastName, EI.FirstName, T.TrainingName AS Training, CT.CompletedDate, EI.Site1, EI.Site2, EI.Site3, CT.ID
FROM tbl_EmployeeInformation AS EI 
INNER JOIN (tbl_CompletedTrainings AS CT 
INNER JOIN tbl_Trainings AS T ON CT.Training = T.AutoID) ON EI.ID = CT.Employee;
```

Comment: I built tables and copy/pasted your query. Victoria is returned. Consider posting to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis, after making a copy and removing/changing confidential data.

Comment: It is not clear to me what issue is. Exactly how can table 'show wrong record'? Title seems to contradict narrative. Data posted has errors. Why is record 4 first and last name values in wrong fields? Training table has "Bloodborne" yet query output shows "Bloodborne Pathogens". Why does 3NNNN have hyphen in one place and not other?

Comment: So the issue is this: Somehow, during the inner join, (Or at least that's where I think the mistake is happening),  The database is taking record 306, assigning it to the wrong person, AND the wrong Training.  As you can see above, in record 306, the training is Clozoril, but when the query runs, it returns Bloodborne Pathogens, and instead of victoria, it returns Eric.  I am going to go back to the start with this I think. Because when I query the table that this is based on (tbl_CompletedTrainings) it also isn't returning the right information, as I said above.

Comment: I used your data and your query. I did not set lookup fields in table. I never do that. However, don't see how lookup fields could be causing this issue.

Comment: On second thought, maybe lookup settings are source of issue. Remove them and see what happens.